# Drupal 7 - Retain checkbox values across pages

Tags: 7, theming, paging, forms

In Drupal 7, I am using tableselect theme with PagerSelect to generate table with checkboxes and pagination. Any thoughts on how to retain checkbox values on pagination?

Answer (score 1):

Store the selected checked box in a database. Load each check box as the pagination goes and check the `#default_value`

example if I had 3 checkbox in a table select for my pagination:

```
$values = array();

$values[1] = TRUE;
$values[2] = FALSE;
$values[3] = TRUE;

$form['table'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $options,
    '#default_value' => $values,
    '#empty' => t('No campground to claim'),
  );
```

Obviously there is more to this, like pagination, but it should get you on the right track.